# Visual Studio 2017 "Script Editor" rejects files with extensions other than '.vbs'

Tags: visual-studio, vbscript, ide

Problem:         I want to edit VBScript files from inside Visual Studio 2017, but the files have the extension '.mts' instead of '.vbs'

Theory:          See helpful article [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/xmlteam/2010/05/02/visual-studio-editor-choosing-system/).

Steps Tried:     I performed a few Registry hacks in order to get 'Script Editor' to show up as a choice in the 'Open With' menu.  However, even now that 'Script Editor' is the default for MTS files, I don't get syntax highlighting when opening them.  The linked article suggest that 'Script Editor' is 'rejecting' the document, causing Visual Studio to default to the base text editor, but I don't see a reason why this should be happening.

Comment: Have you tried the [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) editor?

Comment: @Lankymart Is there a debugger for VBScript in Visual Studio Code? (Active Scripting). I didn't see it when I looked just now. I know you can [debug VBScript with Visual Studio by using some tricks](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/864659/How-to-Debug-Visual-Basic-Script-with-Visual-Studi).

Comment: Not really, if they want to debug then [VbsEdit](http://www.vbsedit.com/) is their best bet as you have already mentioned.

Comment: The VbsEdit debugger is OK, but not like in the olden days.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

1. ***Set Visual Studio Options***: **`Tools => Options => Text Editor => File Extension`**. Add mts extension and set editor to Microsoft Visual Basic - that should do I think.

   [image: Visual Studio Options]
2. ***VbsEdit***: Another alternative could be to use a VBScript tool such as [***VbsEdit***](http://www.vbsedit.com/). I tested it and it seems to apply syntax coloring even for files that do not end in **`*.vbs`**. This is a commercial tool, but is great for VBScripts. It features its own debugger and also an extensive samples library in the **`Samples`** menu (not affiliated).

Comment: Thanks Stein, but the solution shown in your picture doesn't seem to work as well when selecting 'Script Editor' as the 'Editing Experience' (as opposed to 'Microsoft Visual Basic').  The code I am editing is not very friendly to VB proper: it uses the 'Set' keyword, etc.

Comment: I guess the inevitable conclusion is that Microsoft actively tries to kill VBScript? The VbsEdit tool should be possible to use? There is another tool that I haven't tested called "*Splinetech VBS Debugger*".